# How to run stored procedure on DocumentDb Emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Using DocumentDb Emulator, I am able to define my own stored procedure for a certain collection by right-clicking the collection name and choose New Stored Procedure.

My question is: How do I invoke it? The real DocumentDb on Azure Portal has a button called "Save & Execute" which allows me to run it, but that button seems to be missing in the Emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The real DocumentDb on Azure Portal has a button called "Save & Execute" which allows me to run it, but that button seems to be missing in the Emulator.

As you said, Azure Cosmos DB Emulator Data Explorer does not provide [**Save & Execute**] button that enables us to execute the stored procedure directly.

***Azure Cosmos DB Script Explorer on Azure portal:***

[image]

***Azure Cosmos DB Emulator Data Explorer:*** 
 [image]

You can run the stored procedure via code using [Azure Cosmos DB SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sdk-dotnet), the following code works fine on my side.

```
StoredProcedureResponse<object> result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<object>(
    UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("testdb", "testcoll", "SayHello"),param);

var spr = result.Response.ToString();
```

Comment: You can also send email to askdocdb@microsoft.com and give a feedback.

Comment: thanks. So I take it as a no at this time. I wanted to execute the sproc on the emulator itself as I didn't want to pollute the code-base with little snippets that I need to remember to remove everytime I check-in the code. Will mark this as answer since it's the only choice, but feel free to update it when the feature is added. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

With new update, you can run store by click execute button like picture bellow
[image]

Comment: Bizarrely I don't get this button on latest emulator version (1.20.108.4 released on February 14, 2018) and I'm even trying to run the exact same SP!

Comment: Yes, it dont have in Emulator, only in Azureportal